# Android - Google chrome custom font vertical centering issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face, vertical-alignment

I've just experience issue with Font on Google Chrome Android:

[image]
As you can see, it's not vertically centered.

I've tested it on multiple browser (mobile & web), and Google Chrome on android is the only one affected by this issue.

I've tried to only load TTF or SVG, both solution end up not working.

here's the page if you want to test it: http://app.mitoo.co/login

Answer (score 2):

After a long weekend of painful scroll into the dozen of webkit bug reports, I've manage to fix it by opening the font file in [Glyphs](http://www.glyphsapp.com) and exporting them as TTF.

It seems that glyphs automatically calculate and fix the baseline.